# Bumping unanswered question

Tags: discussion

I have posted [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949053/sticky-header-scroll-issue) 20 days ago, and apart from some minor edits immediately after posting, it has received no activity. This is an issue that I have been trying to resolve for some time with no luck, and I think it needs to just get exposure to some fresh sets of eyes in order to be solved.

I posted a Self-Contained, Short, Correct example as I have been instructed in the past, and I feel I did my best in posting this question.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Bam! Sit back and let the meta-effect solve your problem. Because it is a very good question, which around these parts makes it a rarity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Also I am not sure how to handle an answer that does not solve my problem, since the entire point of my question is having the header 'stick' after scrolling to the top of the viewport, and the answer suggests simply fixing it at the top, which is unacceptable.

Comment: @ErikJohnson I'm not an expert in html/css/js however I definitely can't tell what are you saying here. Reading your question and the answer to me it really looks like that the answer *actually* answers your question. This suggest you should probably make it clearer what the problem is, and what you want to achieve, pointed out exactly what's wrong with the current answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu I want the entire page to scroll until the 'header' reaches the top of the screen, and then (and only then) have the header stop scrolling while the remainder of the page's content continues to scroll behind it. Does that make a bit more sense? Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Don't tell us. Edit your question and explain it *there*, where people reading your question can see it.

Comment: @KenWhite that's exactly what I did. The question is now solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meta-effect prevails! @JamesMassey was right. Thanks everyone!

Comment: One thing about the meta effect : while SUPER helpful for good questions (like in your case), it can be hell for bad questions. Basically the meta effect is just giving more exposure to your question. If it's a good one, it helps solving it... if it's a bad one, it gets closed or downvoted even faster

Comment: @ErikJohnson: Asking for votes/accepts is frowned upon, even in jest. Though in some circumstances, it is acceptable to inform the OP that he could accept an answer for his questions, and what that means.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an interesting point - there's several occasions where I've seen questions or answers that ... well, frankly do deserve a bit more interest, but don't get it because of niche areas/tags or just plain 'older' questions.

I conclude a little that this is why the bounty system is there - to allow you to 'pay for' a little more exposure. And reward someone who does a good job, but is unappreciated.

Comment: Agreed, the bounty system would have been more appropriate in normal cases, but the user didn't have enough rep yesterday (before the meta-effect up votes kicked in).

Comment: That's a fair point  - whilst I try and look through 'unanswered, high score questions' I know most look for front page/newest/interesting. I'd be wary of seeing meta used as a bumping ground though...